# css3 - Why can't I set margin based on the resolution?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have CSS below. My screen resolution is 1280x800. Why is my class `.landslide` not getting the margin value `10%`? Right now it's always getting `18%`? Even my screen resolution was 1280x800 which should be matching the max-height:800px.

What am I doing wrong?

```
@media (max-width: 1380px), (max-height: 800px) {
  .contact .landslide {
    margin: 10% auto 0;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1380px), (max-height: 1024px) {
  .contact .landslide {
    margin: 18% auto 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: `max-width` has nothing to do with resolution. It is the width of your browser window. Perhaps you meant `max-device-width` ?

Comment: Should i then use a different @media only with max-height ranges?

Comment: Obviously the above is true of `max-height` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse the rules, otherwise the second one will always overwrite the first one:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1380px) and (max-height: 1024px) {
  .contact .landslide {
    margin: 18% auto 0;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1380px) and (max-height: 800px) {
  .contact .landslide {
    margin: 10% auto 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: NOPE still same. it taking always the first one even the resolution of height is lower then 800px.

Comment: I want if the resolution is 600px then it should get 600 range if the resolution is above 800 then it should take 1024px

Comment: what is the `screen` means here?

Comment: if you have 600 height, both rules will apply (in both the height is below their given max-height), so the 800 rule has to be after the 1024 rule.

Comment: that you are addressing a screen (as opposed to print, for example). The "and"s also are important...

Comment: You're saying in the comments, that you're not getting the desired result, yet you've marked this answer as correct. Is the issue resolved for you @YumYumYum ?

Comment: @Lee: i marked it answer because i learn that using `and` will work for my case, i was using `,` .

Comment: @Lee: i am still confused about the use of `screen` why would i need that?

Comment: So is your problem fixed? And `screen` is used to state the query is to be used for display on a screen, as opposed to say when printing the page (you can declare completely different CSS styling for printing a page)